# init program doesn't work, can't boot the system

Tags: init

Today I opened my Ubuntu and I saw

[image: this]

What should I do ?

Comment: I would boot from a live CD and backup your important data. Then, check your HDD for errors, check the SMART data. Then,  download the boot-repair CD, boot from that and see if it fixes your boot issues. (Not holding my breath but worth a go).  Failing that I personally would re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check the file system to make sure there aren't any errors.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `reboot`

To check the hard disk for hardware errors...

- boot the Ubuntu Live DVD
- choose `Try Ubuntu`
- start the `Disks` application from the Unity dashboard
- click on the "hamburger" icon in the top-right corner of the Disks window and select `SMART Data & Tests`
- review the data, and run the tests
- if you get/see errors, you may have a hard disk problem

If this doesn't help, you're going to need to reinstall Ubuntu. Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD and choose `Install Ubuntu`. Choose `reinstall`, and make sure to **uncheck** the format partition selection, and it'll keep your existing /home directory.